# Starting two intent getting data from first one and start second one

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I want to create a app that will start first intent and select a picture and from second intent by getting path send the image through WiFi or Bluetooth. First intent is like this

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

And second intent will get the image path and send it through selected path.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");


            String uri = Imageurl;
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(uri)));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any way to get intent result in to onCreate ? I meant I am creating these intent results in onCreate. Therefore If I can get results from onCreate then I can use this data to second activity.

Comment: you can get data (path, uri ..  ) in onActivityResult and pass data to your secondActivity by using startActivity method with intent .

Comment: But I needs this result of the first intent inside the Oncreate. I cant use the OnActivityResult due to my application structure